# How do you determine what package is compatible with installed software CentOS 5.8

Tags: centos, httpd, yum, mediatemple

When I do a `yum list httpd` I get the following version returned:

`httpd.x86_64 1:2.2.22-12053112`

When I try to do a `yum install httpd-devel` I get dependency errors like this:

```
httpd-devel-2.2.3-65.el5.centos.3.x86_64 from updates has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: httpd = 2.2.3-65.el5.centos.3 is needed by package httpd-devel-2.2.3-65.el5.centos.3.x86_64 (updates)
Error: Missing Dependency: httpd = 2.2.3-65.el5.centos.3 is needed by package httpd-devel-2.2.3-65.el5.centos.3.x86_64 (updates)
```

**How can I determine what packages I need to install?**

This is on a mediatemple DV 4.

Here is the output of `yum repolist`:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Determining fastest mirrors
 * base: mirrors.lga7.us.voxel.net
 * extras: mirrors.lga7.us.voxel.net
 * updates: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
base                                                     | 1.1 kB     00:00     
base/primary                                             | 1.2 MB     00:00     
base                                                                  3591/3591
extras                                                   | 2.1 kB     00:00     
extras/primary_db                                        | 207 kB     00:00     
updates                                                  | 1.9 kB     00:00     
updates/primary_db                                       | 1.0 MB     00:00     
repo id                        repo name                                  status
base                           CentOS-5 - Base                            3,591
extras                         CentOS-5 - Extras                            279
updates                        CentOS-5 - Updates                         1,215
```

---

**Update:**

I think I made some progress on this. I found this on the plesk forum since mediatemple dv's run plesk.

I made a repository file in `/etc/yum.repo.d/` with the following contents.

```
[Plesk-Apache]
name=Plesk Apache
baseurl=http://autoinstall.plesk.com/APACHE_2.2.21/dist-rpm-CentOS-5-x86_64/
enabled=1
```

Comment: Please run `yum repolist` and post the output.

Answer (score 4):

You've installed a third party repository `webtatic` and the error complains of a missing package from that repository.

Sometimes this happens when your local cache gets out of sync with the state of the repository, and in that case you can just

```
yum clean all
```

and try again.

If that doesn't solve the problem, then you should contact the maintainer of the third party repository to report the problem.

Comment: I ran the command above and then ran yum install httpd-devel got more missing dependency errors. I installed the webtatic after not having any luck with the default repositories. Going to do a clean install of the VM and start over.

Comment: Ok, I reverted the VM to it's original state and updated the post above with appropriate responses I got after doing so.